# Can I run 2 node.js express using https on 2 specific ports?

Tags: node.js, linux, express, https, firewall

I am facing an issue that I am not able to solve alone. I am running 2 node.js server instances on my linux server, but the one running on port 4000 is running well, but the one running on the port 6000 is not working.

**See below the example:**

Port 4000:

[image]

Port 6000:

[image]

**I checked my port on my server and everything seems to be ok:**

[image]

**See below my code for the 2 instances:**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');

var app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(require('body-parser').json());

var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/moreapp.com.br/privkey.pem', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/moreapp.com.br/fullchain.pem', 'utf8');
var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World");
});

httpsServer.listen(6000, () => {
    console.log("Server Listening");
});
```

Could you please help to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: just to check... are the servers contained in different folders or are you literrally running the same code with 2 `.listen` calls? Does the 6000 app run when the 4000 is offline?

Comment: Hi Luiz. I am running the same code in 2 different files. I need the 2 services to  be online at the same time. Thanks

Comment: But does the 4000 works when 6000 is offline?

Comment: just checked both requests, and they worked in postman, but not in the browser. It receives a message "ERR_UNSAFE_PORT" at 6000. Seems a browser issue, actually, with the port 6000. Can you try with another port?

Comment: Yes it works well for the port 4000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should post the complete error for your request.
Which http code you get on port 6000 ?

If you call your servers through a firewall, did you correctly authorized requests on that port ?

EDIT : 
Port 6000 seems to be a forbidden port. He is blocked by many browsers and maybe also by your http tool.
Try to change your port and try again.

Source : [Chrome ports blocked](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/refs/heads/master/net/base/port_util.cc)

Comment: The problem is solved. It was due to the port 6000. I changed it and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add this Error handler at end of your code , and check log what error your are getting

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.log('error ==',err);
    const error = err.message || 'Internal Server Error';
    const status = err.status || 500;
    res.status(status).json({ error: error });
})
```

read more about error handling here : https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: It doesn't appear that the request is getting this far.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the problem. Actually is not with the express app, but with the port 6000, that get "ERR_UNSAFE_PORT" in browser, but works fine as API. Try changing the port, as 6000 is probably system-reserved.

You can read more in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/188006/how-to-fix-err-unsafe-port-error-on-chrome-when-browsing-to-unsafe-ports) issue